# Google Apps Script - automatic email with png from html

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, google-apps-script

I've create a spreadsheet google to collect email and i create a script to automatically send an email with text + png picture. I don't succeed.

Can you help me add the attached file in the automatic email?

name of file : White Diet
html : http://www.puresmile.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Pure-Smile-White-Diet.png

Here is my simple (that work) script but without attached picture in email.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var timestamp = e.values[0];
var Firstname = e.values[1];
 var Lastname = e.values[2];
  var email = e.values[3];

 var subject = "Puresmile White Diet - recommendations 24 hours";
 var body = "Dear customer,\n\n Thank you for visiting Puresmile today.\n Please find the Puresmile White Diet attached. These after care recommendations will explain what to avoid and what's good for your white smile.\n\n To maintain your results for longer please:\n\n * avoid food or beverage (except water) for the next 2 hours after your treatment\n * follow the Puresmile White Diet for 24 hours after the treatment\n\n We hope you enjoyed your experience at our studio today!\n\n Best regards,\n Team Puresmile";

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`MailApp` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29) notes how to include attachments, however it is a bit ambiguous on how to attach images.

I would recommend using the arguments `.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {attachments: [BlobSource]})`

For example:

```
// Set URL of image
var url = "http://www.puresmile.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Pure-Smile-White-Diet.png";

// UrlFetchApp is the class to retrieve hosted content
// .fetch() retrieves the file
// .getBlob returns a "blob" object of the data
// .getAs("image/png") returns a usable PNG image
var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().getAs("image/png");

// Add the "options" to the sendEmail method, 
// where attachments is an array of Blobs
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
    attachments: [image]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried with your code, the email is not sending any more with this code. I just paste your text in replacement of me Mailapp simple version. I checked every line, nothing seems to be wrong. I read that i should always use htmlbody for getting attachments but i don't know how exactly. Thank you for your time !

Comment: I just re-tested the code and it sends the email when I use it.  Is the script giving any errors when it runs?  If so, could you let me know what error(s) it is giving?